# User is not able to commit code in SVN tortoise

Tags: tortoisesvn

We have Four SVN users who work on a common project. The network environment is windows active directory based domain.Three users don't have any issues but fourth user faces issue while committing in SVN tortoise which is below:

Commit  commit
Adding  'e:\projects\project1\tran.php'

Error   Commit succeeded,but no other errors follow:
Error   Error bumping revisions post-commit(details follow):
Error   Can't set file
Error   'e:\projects\project1\tran.php'
Error   read-write:Access is denied.

Answer (score 0):

> Error bumping revisions post-commit

Means: this user have client-side post-commit hook in TortoiseSVN, which doesn't work for *some reason*. Fix error or remove script